# How to draw an RDF graph?

Tags: sql, sparql, rdf, semantic-web, turtle-rdf

I am learning about the semantic web and would like to create an rdf graph of my data

```
@prefix dbc: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:> .
@prefix dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/> .
@prefix dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix dct: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/> .
@prefix skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .

skos:broader rdf:range skos:Concept ;
owl:inverseOf skos:narrower .

dbc:Jane skos:broader dbc:Singer .

dbr:Jane a dbo:Person ;
dct:subject dbc:Singer ,
dbc:Jane .

skos:Concept a owl:Class .

dbc:Abstract_expressionism skos:narrower dbc:Singer .
```

Here is my attempt:

[RDF Generated Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brVWV.png)

I used an RDF graph generator but I am unsure as to whether the results are accurate, my confusion is it did not include the first dbc line *"dbc:Jane skos:broader dbc:Singer ."*

Is this a mistake or is this as expected?

(Added Question) I have also used two prefixes for the same entity, is this acceptable practice or do I need to revise my data.

Comment: Your question does not match the test data. First, you are missing the "dbc;" prefix declaration; second, there is no line you are referring to in your question as the "first dbc line"; third, you are not declaring any namespace with two different prefixes. The way the test data is written in your question, the graph is correct.

Comment: Sorry I fixed the data, I'd appreciate another look

Comment: The graph only captures data starting with the prefixes "dbr" and "skos" the inital "dbc" data is not included in the graph - is this still correct?

Comment: Also, I am referring to "Jane" appearing with two different prefixes in my added question - dbr and dbc @OraLassila

Comment: @Kale what is the name of the RDF generator you used?

Comment: @StratosK http://www.ldf.fi/service/rdf-grapher

Comment: @Kale that's great, many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graph as drawn is correct. It does include the statement about `dbc:Jane` as well. Also note that `dbc:Jane` and `dbr:Jane` are completely different entities, since these names "expand" to different URIs.